# IIS6 wont compress js and css

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, compression, gzip

So recently I configured IIS6 to compress files I now have most files compressing apart from my JavaScript and CSS files. Does anyone have an idea what maybe causing them not to be compressed.

I know this due to Yslow Add-on and the compression directory I have set(see below) is empty

Service Tab Settings:

- Compress application files: checked
- Compress static files: checked
- Temporary directory: %windir%\IIS Temporary Compressed Files
- Max temporary directory size: unlimited

Metabase.xml Snippet:

```
<IIsCompressionScheme   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/deflate"
        HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
        HcCreateFlags="0"
        HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
        HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
        HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
        HcDynamicCompressionLevel="5"
        HcFileExtensions="htm
            html
            txt
            ppt
            xls
            xml
            pdf
            xslt
            doc
            xsl
            htc
            js
            css"
        HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
        HcPriority="1"
        HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
            dll
            exe
            aspx
            asmx
            axd"
    >
</IIsCompressionScheme>
<IIsCompressionScheme   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/gzip"
        HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
        HcCreateFlags="1"
        HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
        HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
        HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
        HcDynamicCompressionLevel="5"
        HcFileExtensions="htm
            html
            txt
            ppt
            xls
            xml
            pdf
            xslt
            doc
            xsl
            htc
            js
            css"
        HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
        HcPriority="1"
        HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
            dll
            exe
            aspx
            asmx
            ashx
            axd"
    >
</IIsCompressionScheme>
```

I have also given IUSR_{machinename} write permissions to "%windir%\IIS Temporary Compressed Files"

What I'm I missing?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the js and css extensions from HcFileExtensions and added them to HcScriptFileExtensions

restarted IIS and its all working

Answer (score 0):

Follow *all* the steps in this tutorial and you should be good:

http://engineering.leads360.com/post/9301650692/http-compression-gzip-on-iis-6